# Adding XML Attribute to a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a class like this,

```
[DataContract]
public class FruitCrate
{
  [XmlAttribute]
  public int NumberOfFruits;

  [DataMember(Name = "Cats")]
  public List<Cats2009> Cats;
}

[DataContract]
public class Cats2009
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;
}
```

Now even if there are no Cats in Fruit Crate, I still want it return result as,

```
<FruitCrate NumberOfFruits="1">
 <cats MomName="BigBadCat" />
</FruitCrate>
```

Comment: Where does MomName come from in your example?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs That's the problem, I don't know where to declare "MomName" attribute

Comment: Then you will need to have a custom object CatContainer named cats that has the List<Cats> and has a property MomName.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs thank you, I am trying to understand your comment, can you add a example in answer pleazo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[DataContract]
public class FruitCrate
{
  [XmlAttribute]
  public int NumberOfFruits;

  [DataMember(Name = "Cats")]
  public CatContainer CatContainer;
}

[DataContract]
public class Cats2009
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;
}
[DataContract]
public class CatContainer
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string MomName;

    [DataMember]
    public List<Cats2009> Cats;
}
```

Try this. I don't have much experience with XmlAttribute so I don't quite know how it works, but this should do. Note that you will always have to declare a CatContainer, but it doesn't have to contain any cats.

---

I did some research of my own, and you cannot use DataContract if you want XmlAttributes. You will have to Implement ISerializable or use the .NET XmlSerializer.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't fully tested the solution yet, but I believe it should work, and also using XmlAttributes shouldn't have a problem, I will tell you how i fix the issue if arose.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a method and mark it with the attribute [OnSerialized]/[OnDeserialized]. This will allow you to change the contents of the "Cats" if it is null or empty to "BigBadCat". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx